# React doesn't display my resized picture. Why?

Tags: reactjs, image-resizing

My app launches without error message but I can't figure out why my picture isn't displayed.

```
import React from 'react';
import rec from '../images/rec.jpg';
import Resizer from 'react-image-file-resizer';

class Recumbent extends React.Component {

    resizeFile = (file) => new Promise(resolve => {
            Resizer.imageFileResizer(file, 300, 200, 'JPEG', 100, 0,
            uri => {
              resolve(uri);
            },
            'base64'
            );
        });

    render() {
        return <img src={this.resizeFile(rec.blob)} alt="recumbent" />
    }
}

export default Recumbent;
```

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: This is my snippet. It just doesn't do what I am expecting (in my app it only displays the alt text (recumbent).

Comment: so create demo of your problem so we can solve it asap

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import rec from "./picture.jpg";
import Resizer from "react-image-file-resizer";

const resizeFile = async (file) => {
  const image = await fetch(rec);
  const imageBlob = await image.blob();

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(
      imageBlob,
      300,
      300,
      "JPEG",
      100,
      0,
      (uri) => {
        resolve(uri);
      },
      "base64"
    );
  });
};

const App = () => {
  const [uri, setUri] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function uriAfterResize(file) {
      const image = await resizeFile(file);
      setUri(image);
    }
    uriAfterResize(rec);
  }, []);

  return <img src={uri ? uri : ""} alt="recumbent" />;
};

export default App;
```

The approach you were using before doesn't account for the fact that your `resizeFile` function returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Meaning that retrieving the `base64` image is an asynchronous process.

My example approach waits until after the promise has resolved the `uri` we want, after which we update some state that is passed conditionally to the `src` prop of the image.